# jQuery making forms disappear and appear after each other

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

As the title says This is the code that I tried with. The forms must appear one by one because information from previous forms determine how the next ones will look.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#first_form').submit(function(){
        $('#first_form').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#second_form').fadeIn('fast');   
    });
});
```

```
<form action="new_patch.php" method="POST" id="first_form">
Title: <input type="text" name="patch" placeholder="Patch 4.20">
<br/>
Number of Champions: <input type="number" name="champ_number" min="1" max="99">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form action="new_patch.php" method="POST" id="second_form" style="display: none;" >
<input type="text" value="text">
<input type="submit" value="submit">

<?php


    $champ_number = null;
    if(isset($_POST['champ_number']))
    {
        $champ_number = $_POST['champ_number'];


    for($champ_number;$champ_number>0;$champ_number--)
    {

        echo "<br/>Champion ".$champ_number."<input type=\"number\" name=".$champ_number." min=\"1\" max=\"99\">";
    }
    }

?>

</form>
```

Comment: it doesn't work I've heard that I need to put return false; after first form but then the second one doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$('#first_form').submit(function(){
    $('#first_form').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#second_form').fadeIn('fast');
    });
    return false;
});
```

From the jQuery documentation the syntax is `fadeIn( [duration ] [, complete ] )` it accepts a duration and a `onComplete` callback that you can use to execute the next action when the first is completed.

Comment: I tried this way and nothing happens after clicking submit here is the full code : http://pastebin.com/gRnb9F1P

Comment: the first submit or second?

Comment: the first form is always shwoing up even when I fill it with data and click submit the site just refreshes with blank form 1 still

Comment: See the updated code I added a return false on the submt function

Comment: it changes the first form to the second one but skips the PHP

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing client-side and server-side form code. Submitting the form will reload the page entirely, so from the looks of your code it will fade in the new form when the old form is submitted, but then reload the page so the old form will show again anyway.

You could either:

- Let the PHP determine how the next form appears based on the submission of the first form, e.g. `if (isset($_POST["First_form_submit"]) { Show second form... }`
- Probably better and more user-friendly: make the second form appear below once the user has filled in the relevant inputs on the first form before they've submitted

Comment: could you elaborate on the second method? it seems interesting

Comment: You could add a `div` that comprises the second form to the page, giving it the class **not-here** with the style **display: none**. Then write a jQuery function that removes that class (**.removeClass("not-here")**) once the user has filled in the inputs of the first form.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once too, just add a **submit** class to the button and make it like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
```

Change script to a click function.

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        $('#first_form').fadeOut(400);
        $('#second_form').fadeIn(400);   
    });
});
```

PS, also you need to prevent submit default...otherwise it will just submit the form, see this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nu8wgao/1/)

Comment: tried that as well nothing happens after clicking submit

Comment: yeah I got to that point few times already but check the http://pastebin.com/gRnb9F1P the php part still doesn't work

Comment: That has nothing to do with your question...you only asked for a jquery that fadesIn/Out between your forms.

Comment: that php is a part of the form

Comment: This is your question : "jQuery making forms disappear and appear after each other" , right? Where is the "php doesn't work" in your question ? Or in the description ?